# Unable to connect with my google VM instance

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-instances

We are unable to connect with our google cloud Linux VM instance, Suddenly started receiving the below error. It is happening since last week.

1. We tried to launch the new instance using by creating an image but that instance also had the same issue.
2. We increase the disk space, rebooted the instance, and try login in again, but still could not work.

How can we solve it and get login into our instance?

> Connection Failed You cannot connect to the VM instance because of an
> unexpected error. Wait a few moments and then try again. See
> troubleshooting docs.

**UPDATES:
Tried to connect with a standers SSH client like putty, and I am able to access my instance, However, still having this issue while connecting from Google Console.**

**This may help someone to proceed with their work, instead of waiting to resolve the google console issue.**

[image]

Comment: To help with debugging, use a standard SSH client with debugging enabled. Post the command and output in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley - Connection from standard SSH client is working fine. Added an update on my question.

Comment: Did you create a VPC firewall ingress rule allowing IAP? Allow traffic from `35.235.240.0/20`. https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule

Comment: In order to provide a better solution for your issue, please refer to the GCP [support hub](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) and request to file a support case, they have access to inspect your projects, logs, and can provide support with any issue regarding GCP console.